# Uncaught Invalid argument: Instance of 'Node'

Tags: dart

When working with a sort function, the implemented node i had created seems to cause some issues.

I have tracked it down to the comparison of Nodes in the Merge function of MergeSort.  That being said, the line of code in question is:

```
if (_tmpArray[i] <= _tmpArray[j])
```

_tmpArray is defined in the the constructor, but given content value in the  merge

Node implementation of `operator ==`, `operator <`, `operator <=` are as follows.

```
bool operator ==( Node<T> other) => identical(this, other);
bool operator <( Node<T> other){
  //other is of same type, T.
  if (_value.compareTo(other) == -1){
    return true;
  }
  return false;

}
bool operator <= ( Node<T> other){
  return (this == other) || (this < other);
}
```

It seems that maybe my implementation is wrong.  I am doing a test inside of main with a List of size 400, of T = int.

Attached is my Dartpad file: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/612422345f1ac8a27f8e

It seems that the comparison of:  `_value.compareTo` is not correct because `T` doesnt have compareTo in this case of `int` being `T`.  When converting the int to "String" which is comparable though `compareTo` it still shows the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//other is of same type, T.
if (_value.compareTo(other._value) == -1){
//                        ^^^^^^^ was missing
  return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I forgot that when i moved Node to extend Comparable to T extending it, i had forgot to update that.